# Присвоение значения вложенному словарю в цикле python

Tags: python, for, dict

Не могу понять и исправить ситуацию с присвоением значения во вложенном словаре в цикле:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
import openpyxl, time

report_book = 'xls/DOR.xlsx' #адрес отчета

summ_coll_if = 'Сумма продаж (руб.)' #столбец по которому идет суммирование

set_stream = {'Традиция',}

set_category = {'SD Red', 'FD', 'DG Capsules', 'DG Equipment', 'MIXES', 
                'SD Gold', 'BISTROFF', 'Breakfast Cereals', 'Cereal bars', 
                'BOXES', 'TABLETS', 'COUNTLINES', 'SUGAR', 'CONFETTI', 
                'CULINARY', 'PURINA', 'OTHER DRINKS'}

set_people = {'TSM1', 'TSM2' }

set_tier = {'Tier TT', 'Tier 3'}

def SummValue (report: str, summ_coll: str, set_people: set, set_category: set, set_tier: set, set_stream: set, book_list: int) -> dict:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(report, read_only=False, data_only=True) # открываем книгу
    wb.active = book_list # делаем первый лист активным
    sheet = wb.active # присваиваем переменной активный лист
    summ = 0
    result_dict = dict.fromkeys(set_people, dict.fromkeys(set_tier, dict.fromkeys(set_stream, dict.fromkeys(set_category, 0)))) #создаем словарь

    for cell in sheet['1']: # ищим в заголовках колонку для суммирования
        if cell.value == summ_coll: # проверяем колонку для суммирования
            column = get_column_letter(cell.column) # преобразем кол-ный кол колонки в адрес

            for i in sheet[column]: # проверяем каждую строку колонки
                if i.value != cell.value: # если строка != названию

                    list_of_values = set() # создаем пустое множество

                    for cell in sheet[i.row]: # проходим по всем значениям текущей строки
                        list_of_values.add(cell.value) # все значения текущей строки добавляем в множество

                    for people in set_people:
                        new_set = set()
                        new_set.add(people)
                        for tier in set_tier:
                            new_set1 = set()
                            new_set1.update(new_set)
                            new_set1.add(tier)
                            for stream in set_stream:
                                new_set2 = set()
                                new_set2.update(new_set1)
                                new_set2.add(stream)
                                for category in set_category:
                                    new_set3 = set()
                                    new_set3.update(new_set2)
                                    new_set3.add(category)              
                                    if new_set3.intersection(list_of_values) == new_set3:
                                        summ = result_dict[people][tier][stream][category] + i.value
                                        summ = float('{0:.2f}'.format(summ))
                                        result_dict[people][tier][stream][category] = summ
                                    else:
                                        continue
    return result_dict

result = SummValue(report_book, summ_coll_if, set_people, set_category, set_tier, set_stream, 0)

print(result)
```

На данный момент данная функция присваивает всем `people`, `tier`, `stream` и `category` одно и тоже значение `summ`, хотя в документе .xlsx данные суммы разные.

Вот результат данной функции:

```
{'TSM2': 
{'Tier 3': 
{'Традиция': 
{'BOXES': 5722.96, 'CONFETTI': 0, 'PURINA': 371448.13, 'CULINARY': 296151.43, 'OTHER DRINKS': 0, 'DG Capsules': 2438.46, 'Cereal bars': 113197.03, 'COUNTLINES': 538179.44, 'TABLETS': 133178.0, 'DG Equipment': 0, 'BISTROFF': 23278.92, 'SUGAR': 27448.54, 'FD': 1091256.04, 'MIXES': 267983.8, 'SD Gold': 0, 'Breakfast Cereals': 263496.46, 'SD Red': 1311766.14}}, 
'Tier TT': 
{'Традиция': 
{'BOXES': 5722.96, 'CONFETTI': 0, 'PURINA': 371448.13, 'CULINARY': 296151.43, 'OTHER DRINKS': 0, 'DG Capsules': 2438.46, 'Cereal bars': 113197.03, 'COUNTLINES': 538179.44, 'TABLETS': 133178.0, 'DG Equipment': 0, 'BISTROFF': 23278.92, 'SUGAR': 27448.54, 'FD': 1091256.04, 'MIXES': 267983.8, 'SD Gold': 0, 'Breakfast Cereals': 263496.46, 'SD Red': 1311766.14}}}, 
'TSM1': 
{'Tier 3': 
{'Традиция': 
{'BOXES': 5722.96, 'CONFETTI': 0, 'PURINA': 371448.13, 'CULINARY': 296151.43, 'OTHER DRINKS': 0, 'DG Capsules': 2438.46, 'Cereal bars': 113197.03, 'COUNTLINES': 538179.44, 'TABLETS': 133178.0, 'DG Equipment': 0, 'BISTROFF': 23278.92, 'SUGAR': 27448.54, 'FD': 1091256.04, 'MIXES': 267983.8, 'SD Gold': 0, 'Breakfast Cereals': 263496.46, 'SD Red': 1311766.14}}, 
'Tier TT': 
{'Традиция': 
{'BOXES': 5722.96, 'CONFETTI': 0, 'PURINA': 371448.13, 'CULINARY': 296151.43, 'OTHER DRINKS': 0, 'DG Capsules': 2438.46, 'Cereal bars': 113197.03, 'COUNTLINES': 538179.44, 'TABLETS': 133178.0, 'DG Equipment': 0, 'BISTROFF': 23278.92, 'SUGAR': 27448.54, 'FD': 1091256.04, 'MIXES': 267983.8, 'SD Gold': 0, 'Breakfast Cereals': 263496.46, 'SD Red': 1311766.14}}}}
```

[Пример файла](https://yadi.sk/i/28ZU9OeEYkpedA).

Вот то что хочу получить на выходе из данных файла на примере одного `people`, т.е. по данному человеку должны быть заполнены только данные в `Tier TT`:

```
{'TSM1': 
{'Tier 3': 
{'Традиция': 
{'BOXES': 0, 'CONFETTI': 0, 'PURINA': 0, 'CULINARY': 0, 'OTHER DRINKS': 0, 'DG Capsules': 0, 'Cereal bars': 0, 'COUNTLINES': 0, 'TABLETS': 0, 'DG Equipment': 0, 'BISTROFF': 0, 'SUGAR': 0, 'FD': 0, 'MIXES': 0, 'SD Gold': 0, 'Breakfast Cereals': 0, 'SD Red': 0}}, 
'Tier TT': 
{'Традиция': 
{'BOXES': 0, 'CONFETTI': 0, 'PURINA': 0, 'CULINARY': 153362.22, 'OTHER DRINKS': 0, 'DG Capsules': 0, 'Cereal bars': 51489,31, 'COUNTLINES': 463559, 'TABLETS': 46737.20, 'DG Equipment': 0, 'BISTROFF': 0, 'SUGAR': 8280, 'FD': 618453, 'MIXES': 174474, 'SD Gold': 0, 'Breakfast Cereals': 11169, 'SD Red': 1212746,26}}}}
```

Comment: Можете выложить небольшой  Excel файл на каком-нибудь файлообменнике и привести в вопросе пример того, что хотите получить на выходе? PS такую обработку данных гораздо проще делать пользуясь модулем Pandas

Comment: Добавил файл .xlsx для примера, и что должно получиться на выходе.
Я новичок в Python, спасибо за подсказку с Pandas, попробую по гуглить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

cols = dict(
    cat="категория ID",
    esr="ESR",
    amt="Сумма продаж (руб.)",
    stream="Стрим ТК",
    tier="Tier",
)

filename = r"D:\download\DOR.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

grp_by = [cols["esr"], cols["tier"], cols["stream"], cols["cat"]]
res = df.groupby(grp_by)[cols["amt"]].sum()
```

результат в виде Pandas.Series:

```
In [23]: res
Out[23]:
ESR   Tier     Стрим ТК  категория ID
TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция  0                      20654.64
                         Breakfast Cereals      11169.00
                         COUNTLINES            463559.00
                         CULINARY              153362.22
                         Cereal bars            51489.31
                         FD                   1012792.48
                         MIXES                 174474.00
                         SD Red               1212746.26
                         SUGAR                   8280.00
                         TABLETS                46737.20
TSM2  Tier 3   Традиция  0                      10197.24
                         BISTROFF               23278.92
                         BOXES                   5722.96
                         Breakfast Cereals     252327.46
                         COUNTLINES             74620.44
                         CULINARY              142789.21
                         Cereal bars            61707.72
                         DG Capsules             2438.46
                         FD                     78463.56
                         MIXES                  93509.80
                         PURINA                371448.13
                         SD Red                 99019.88
                         SUGAR                  19168.54
                         TABLETS                86440.80
Name: Сумма продаж (руб.), dtype: float64
```

результат в виде Pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [24]: res.reset_index()
Out[24]:
     ESR     Tier  Стрим ТК       категория ID  Сумма продаж (руб.)
0   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция                  0             20654.64
1   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция  Breakfast Cereals             11169.00
2   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция         COUNTLINES            463559.00
3   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция           CULINARY            153362.22
4   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция        Cereal bars             51489.31
5   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция                 FD           1012792.48
6   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция              MIXES            174474.00
7   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция             SD Red           1212746.26
8   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция              SUGAR              8280.00
9   TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция            TABLETS             46737.20
10  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция                  0             10197.24
11  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция           BISTROFF             23278.92
12  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция              BOXES              5722.96
13  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция  Breakfast Cereals            252327.46
14  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция         COUNTLINES             74620.44
15  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция           CULINARY            142789.21
16  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция        Cereal bars             61707.72
17  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция        DG Capsules              2438.46
18  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция                 FD             78463.56
19  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция              MIXES             93509.80
20  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция             PURINA            371448.13
21  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция             SD Red             99019.88
22  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция              SUGAR             19168.54
23  TSM2   Tier 3  Традиция            TABLETS             86440.80
```

---

Чтобы обратиться к определенному значению в Pandas.Series c мультииндексом:

```
In [37]: res.loc[pd.IndexSlice["TSM1", "Tier TT", "Традиция", "SD Red"]]
Out[37]: 1212746.26
```

В случае DataFrame можно воспользоваться методом `df.query()`:

```
tab = res.reset_index()  # преобразуем multi-index Series -> DataFrame
q = f'''`{cols["esr"]}` == "TSM1" and `{cols["cat"]}` in ("Cereal bars", "SD Red")'''

In [56]: tab.query(q)
Out[56]:
    ESR     Tier  Стрим ТК категория ID  Сумма продаж (руб.)
4  TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция  Cereal bars             51489.31
7  TSM1  Tier TT  Традиция       SD Red           1212746.26
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @Владимир, рад был помочь)